# Is this the correct closed form for a series similar to $\zeta(2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I hope this question is well received. I don't have a computer that can calculate very many terms for the infinite series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^{2}},$$
but is it going to equal to this closed form: $\log(2.5)$?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function

Answer (score 7):

The sum is equal to [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant), which is close but not equal to $\log(5/2).$ The difference between the two is $-0.000325138$

Comment: Thank you very much. May your best day of the past be the worst day of your future! Bill

Comment: But, it doesn't appear to have a closed form after looking at the literature, just G?

Comment: I just know that this is a special value of a Dirichlet L-function at 2

Comment: @user124808 At least it's not known to -- the sum you've given is the usual *definition* of Catalan's constant. But it is an open problem even to determine whether $G$ is a rational number.

Comment: ...and it is an open problem even to determine whether $G$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^2$.  A conjecture based on the flimsy evidence of $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, since this series is the $L$-function of the nontrivial character mod $4$, which is an *odd* character (the trivial character, which is even, is related to the zeta-function), the value should be thought of as like odd zeta-values rather than even zeta-values, so we shouldn't expect the series to have any simple relation to powers of $\pi$. For comparison, $L(1,\chi_4) = \pi/4$ and $L(3,\chi_4) = \pi^3/32$ are rational multiples of suitable powers of $\pi$.